# Driving MOSFET with 26kHz PWM from NE555, MOSFET not opening completly

Tags: pwm, mosfet-driver

[image: schematic]
First sorry for my english. The problem is it looks like MOSFET is not opening completely, and I do not have any equipment except crappy 5$ multimeter. I measured 3 points on the PCB, they are marked on the schematic. What confuse me, is that when I remove motor from circuit, and leave drain not connected to anything, I get 12V betwen VCC and drain, but when I connect the motor, voltage drops. If spinning, the motor consumes ~120mA, also the motor is not rated for 12V, but it's just a test, and I doesn't care. For PWM generating I'm using NE555, and for driving MOSFET BC327, and BC337. I wanted to make a high voltage generator, but for tests, I'm using small DC motor salvaged from RC car.

photos of PCB: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n73gN.jpg (I don't have 10rep, so I can only add 2 links)

Comment: You cannot measure the voltages you marked "6.3V", "6.5V" and "8.7 V" properly with a multimeter when the 555 is operating and generating a square wave. These voltages are square-waves so you need an **oscilloscope** to measure properly. You can check the voltages in a static way, connecting the PWM input either to GND or VCC. You're using a 100 pF timing cap with the 555, that's a **bad** idea, it is too small. I would not go below 1 nF. Even better use 10 nF. Reduce the values of R3 and R4 with the same factor (so make both 2.7 kohm).

Comment: If your comfortable with KiCad now might be a good time to learn LTspice you have some major schematic issues with your 555

Comment: I'm too lazy to calculate the switching frequency you're trying to make but if it is low enough (below 10 kHz perhaps) then the 555 is powerfull enough to drive the BUZ11 directly. You have Q1 and Q2 in an emitter-follower config. which results in some voltage drop which does not help.

Comment: To see what the actual PWM high and low voltages are without an oscilloscope, make C2 much larger (eg. 10uF) so the period is several seconds.

Comment: why can't the PWM connect directly to the MOSFET?

Comment: @dandavis I wanted to turn off, and on MOSFET at rate ~25kHz, so I have to charge, and discharge internal gate capacity very fast, in with case NE555 would be not enough to provide that much current.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would strongly recommend you to add a parallel diode to the motor with its anode connected to MOSFET's drain and with its cathode to +12V. This diode should be schotky (1N5819) or fast recovery silicon (FRxxx, HERxxx, SFxx). This is done to prevent the inductive voltage overshoot of motor's winding right after MOSFET is turned off.

Second - your parallel capacitor 100nF is too big for PWM control. Each cycle the transistor is turned on a large amount of current will pass through this cap and heat up the transistor. A value of 1nF to 10nF maximum would be OK. If there is plenty emitted noise due to motor brushes (this is the main function of this cap) you could place a resistor in series with the capacitor - something like a 10-47 ohm. This way the stress on the MOSFET will be reduced significantly while the capacitor still does its job with motor brushes.

Measuring 8.7V at the drain makes me think that there are significant voltage overshoot after each turn off and thus the average value is high. Measure that again after placing the diode.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]
Missing diode, that was it. So I slightly modified my schematic, I changed R3,R4 to 2,7k, and C2 to 1nF, and added transformer from CCLF inventer, and added radiator to MOSFET, I used CPU thermal compound. Now the problem is that MOSFET gets hot very fast, I mean ~5sec and MOSFET, and the radiator is sth around 40-50degrees. I do get small spark on secondary coil, around 1cm. Also, the diode was getting very hot with the transformer, so I added a 5W 0,47Ohm resistor in series. Here is schematic, and photo of the transformer, and radiator. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEHdY.jpg What I have to do to make MOSFET cooler? I suppose it's because I have only 3 turns on primary, maybe this transformer is not suitable for this application? Also, I think that the MOSFET is opening completely, because when I connect big motor, with consumes 1,5A and I run it for 2min, MOSFET is still cold.

Comment: Do you actually have threshold connected to your supply and Vcc connected to R3?

Comment: Actually no, It's an old version of a schematic , I overlooked this because PWM works just fine. I actually used this to create the circuit http://imgur.com/z6CCQu3

Comment: That makes sense, @Richard Thiessen wrote a good answer yesterday that would apply here as well https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307074/dc-square-wave-transformer

Comment: "the diode was getting very hot " - what's the diode part number?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I don't know, it was ripped from old computer PSU, I blow up the first one, but the second one was also getting hot very fast, so I added a 5W resistor. I suppose it's flimsy solution.

Comment: @sstobbe Thanks, that clarified a lot, now I decided to go with half-bridge, can you check my schematic? http://imgur.com/a/5z6qE Also I don't know what value C1, and C2 should I choose, and more important why "that" value I have to choose.

Comment: C1, C2 values, brands, types and condition should be the same. To calculate their value you should know how much average current runs through the transofmer's primary. The capacitance should be enought so that current will not make more than 5-10% ripple. The less the better. ... A *ripped* component from somewhere without knowing its parameters is... just not serious.