# DC square wave Transformer

Tags: power, transformer, dc

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWIIwM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have dc into a bunch of 555 timers to create a square wave single that goes into the gate of the n-channel mosfet. im trying to power a transformer with 60 volts dc power. the resistance on the primary coil of transformer is 4 ohms. why will this not work? i do a open circuit test on transformer. it pulls more than 2 amps with no load. need some advice. i just need this transformer to work

Comment: You need to push and pull, or else you will run your xfmr up to its saturation current, perhaps google "12 volt inverter schematic" for inspiration

Comment: how can you push pull dc currect

Comment: sorry how can you push pull with a mosfet switch

Comment: Sample of a low cost inverter, http://www.electroschematics.com/9155/12v-to-220v-voltage-inverter/ can you use a transformer with a center tap

Comment: yes i was just looking at that site. i dont have a center tap on this transformer. i can get one designed tho. my problem is that i have a square wave freq gen from 0-10khz that i must change freq. so im trying to go from 20 volts(pwm) to 3500 volts(out put of transformer) i though i could just push dc and the transformer would work.

Comment: What kind of square wave do you need at the output of the transformer or do you just need DC out?

Comment: Given the voltages you are looking for, have a look here: http://www.diyphysics.com/category/instrumentation/high-voltage-power-supply/

Comment: thanks jonk i will read all of that thanks for your advice all the help i can get. im doing research on inverter going into a transformer and how it will look on the output. if the output positive rail is ac(sine wave) i dont think i can use it. it has to be only positive voltage on the positive rail of output of transformer. im trying to find that info now. but i can pretty easily test the inverter tomorrow so i will do that. also how would you control the current in that circuit

Answer (score 1):

First, D1 and D2 in the above diagram serve no purpose. They drop 1.2 volts from the power supply. That's it. I just wanted to get that out of the way.

Transformers are tricky. They don't just give the input voltage times the turns ratio. Transformers can only pass alternating current. Balanced alternating current. If the voltage across them has a DC component, the current on the primary side will increase in the direction of that DC component until the primary resistance cancels it out and/or the transformer saturates. You never want that to happen. For every Volt*second you apply in one direction you have to apply another volt*second at a later point in the operating cycle to balance it out. This keeps the current from building up in one direction.

Here's a simplified version of your circuit in my favourite circuit simulator. Notice how the current just keeps on going up and up and up.

**(click it, it's a link!!)**

[image]

What you need is to switch the voltage to the opposite value for at least half the cycle. Here's what that looks like:

[image]

Here, we use two diodes and two switches. The diodes let the built up current run backwards, dumping energy back into the power supply. Try playing around with that circuit. You'll find that bringing the duty cycle above 50% causes the same problem as in the previous design, the current just keeps increasing. You're applying 60 volts in one direction for more than half the duty cycle and 60 volts in the other direction for the rest which makes the current build up in one direction as it did before.

## Half bridge and Full bridge topologies

The most used topology in power electronics is the half bridge. You find it everywhere from DC-DC point of load converters to motor drivers to Utility scale  HVDC power conversion Put two of them together to get a full bridge.

[Here's what your finished circuit would look like.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%205e-7%202.1831051418620846%2028%205%2043%0AT%20224%20192%20288%20240%202%200.000009999999999999999%20100%20-7.489650208926705%200.08689185419709895%200.99999%0Aw%20192%2064%20128%2064%200%0AR%20128%200%20128%20-32%200%200%2040%2060%200%200%200.5%0A159%20128%2064%20128%20128%201%201%2010000000000%0Ag%20128%20128%20128%20160%200%0Aw%20192%2064%20192%20240%200%0Aw%20288%20240%20288%20304%200%0Ag%20288%20304%20288%20336%200%0Aw%20384%20304%20336%20304%200%0Al%20384%20192%20288%20192%200%200.15%200.08689185419711455%0A159%20128%200%20128%2064%200%201%2010000000000%0Aw%20112%2032%20112%2096%200%0Ar%20336%20304%20288%20304%200%200.1%0Aa%20368%20320%20368%20400%200%205%200%201000000%20-0.008689185419711499%200%0Aw%20224%2064%20272%2064%200%0Ac%20304%2064%20304%200%202%200.000009999999999999999%20-32.989955756753254%0Ac%20304%2064%20304%20128%202%200.000009999999999999999%2027.010044243246746%0Aw%20272%200%20304%200%200%0Aw%20224%20192%20224%2064%200%0Aw%20272%200%20128%200%200%0Aw%20368%20400%20112%20400%200%0Aw%20112%20400%20112%2096%200%0Ad%20272%2064%20272%200%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20272%20128%20272%2064%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20304%20128%20272%20128%200%0Aw%20304%2064%20272%2064%200%0Aw%20272%20128%20128%20128%200%0Ar%20224%20240%20192%20240%200%204%0Aw%20368%20400%20656%20400%200%0Aw%20384%20304%20384%20320%200%0A159%20816%2064%20816%200%201%201%2010000000000%0A159%20816%20128%20816%2064%200%201%2010000000000%0Ar%20768%20240%20736%20240%200%204%0Aw%20816%20128%20672%20128%200%0Aw%20656%20144%20656%2096%200%0Aw%20656%20144%20656%20400%200%0Aw%20816%200%20672%200%200%0Aw%20768%20192%20768%2064%200%0Aw%20768%2064%20816%2064%200%0Ar%20880%20304%20832%20304%200%200.1%0Aw%20656%2032%20656%2096%200%0A159%20672%200%20672%2064%200%201%2010000000000%0Al%20928%20192%20832%20192%200%200.15%200.1339187686417963%0Aw%20928%20304%20880%20304%200%0Ac%20928%20192%20928%20304%202%201e-9%201658.0800959024712%0Ag%20832%20304%20832%20336%200%0Aw%20832%20240%20832%20304%200%0Aw%20736%2064%20736%20240%200%0Ag%20672%20128%20672%20160%200%0A159%20672%2064%20672%20128%201%201%2010000000000%0AR%20672%200%20672%20-32%200%200%2040%2060%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20736%2064%20672%2064%200%0AT%20768%20192%20832%20240%202%200.000009999999999999999%20100%20-11.195321834712143%200.13391876864177776%200.99999%0Aw%20832%2032%20832%2096%200%0Aw%20832%2096%20832%20144%200%0Aw%20832%20144%20656%20144%200%0Ac%20384%20192%20384%20304%200%201e-9%20910.3111847800745%0Ax%20161%20-21%20294%20-18%204%2024%20Half%5Csbridge%0Ax%20698%20-17%20824%20-14%204%2024%20Full%5Csbridge%0Ao%2056%208%200%204099%202560%200.2%200%202%2056%203%0A) The switches stand in for MOSFETs. I'll get to the practical implementation in a little bit.

In this case, the transformer is the Load the half or full bridge drives. Everything is nice and symmetric. With a half bridge configuration you only drive the transformer with half the input voltage. You also have to make sure the capacitors on the other side don't empty out. Try reducing their size or increasing the resonant frequency of the system and see what happens. (That's why the diodes are there.)

Implementing a half bridge is pretty simple. You need an independent 12-20V power supply sitting referenced to your power voltage. Add a few diodes BJTs and resistors and that's it. [Here's the circuit for driving a single half bridge.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%200.20306040966347483%2048%205%2050%0At%20560%20272%20608%20272%200%20-1%201.000000082740371e-10%204.99999930347883e-10%20100%0Ad%20560%20224%20608%20224%201%200.805904783%0Aw%20608%20224%20608%20256%200%0Aw%20560%20224%20560%20272%200%0Af%20640%20256%20688%20256%200%201.5%200.2%0Aw%20688%20240%20688%20192%200%0AR%20688%20192%20688%20128%200%200%2040%2030%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20688%20336%20608%20336%200%0Aw%20688%20272%20688%20336%200%0Av%20608%20192%20608%20128%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20560%20128%20608%20128%200%0Ar%20560%20272%20560%20336%200%201000%0Aw%20608%20336%20560%20336%200%0Aw%20608%20288%20608%20336%200%0Aw%20608%20256%20640%20256%200%0At%20496%20176%20560%20176%200%20-1%2044.72451187507624%20-4.4998671455687145e-11%20100%0Aw%20560%20128%20560%20160%200%0At%20432%20320%20496%20320%200%201%20-29.999999999955%20-4.999911595859885e-11%20100%0Ar%20496%20336%20496%20416%200%201000%0Aw%20496%20304%20496%20176%200%0Ag%20688%20480%20688%20528%200%0Ar%20496%20176%20496%20128%200%20300%0Aw%20496%20128%20560%20128%200%0Aw%20560%20192%20560%20224%200%0Af%20608%20416%20688%20416%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20688%20336%20688%20400%200%0Aw%20688%20432%20688%20480%200%0AL%20496%20416%20368%20416%200%201%20false%2015%200%0Ar%20688%20336%20848%20336%200%20200%0AR%20848%20336%20896%20336%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20608%20416%20496%20416%200%0AR%20432%20320%20432%20272%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20688%20192%20608%20192%200%0A) The independent power supply can be produced by a [charge pump](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%205e-7%201.5642631884188172%2059%205%2050%0A165%20480%20304%20544%20304%202%201.3797087265233025e-14%0Ar%20480%20496%20624%20496%200%2010000%0Ac%20480%20496%20480%20560%200%205e-9%208.526545325530172%0Aw%20480%20496%20480%20432%200%0Aw%20480%20432%20480%20400%200%0Aw%20624%20496%20624%20368%200%0Aw%20608%20368%20624%20368%200%0Aw%20608%20336%20608%20272%200%0Aw%20608%20272%20544%20272%200%0AR%20544%20272%20544%20224%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20480%20560%20480%20592%200%0Ac%20624%20368%20752%20368%202%200.000001%20-99.34001118300804%0Ad%20752%20416%20752%20368%201%200.805904783%0Ad%20752%20368%20752%20320%201%200.805904783%0AR%20992%20416%20992%20368%200%200%2040%20100%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20992%20416%20912%20416%200%0Ac%20832%20320%20832%20416%202%200.000009999999999999999%2013.652432349343599%0Aw%20752%20320%20832%20320%200%0Aw%20752%20416%20832%20416%200%0AO%20832%20320%20832%20288%201%0Ar%20912%20416%20912%20320%200%2010000%0Aw%20832%20320%20912%20320%200%0Aw%20912%20416%20832%20416%200%0Af%20928%20496%20992%20496%200%201.5%200.02%0Af%20928%20560%20992%20560%200%201.5%200.02%0Aw%20992%20512%20992%20528%200%0Aw%20992%20528%201072%20528%200%0Aw%20992%20544%20992%20528%200%0Aw%20992%20480%20992%20416%200%0Aw%20992%20576%20992%20608%200%0Ag%20992%20608%20992%20640%200%0Ao%2011%2016%200%2012289%200.0001%200.0244501006022233%200%202%2011%203%0Ao%2016%2016%200%204099%2020%200.1%201%202%2016%203%0A). For prototyping it's easier to just use an independent lab supply for both but for the finished product a charge pump is just the circuit above. A 555 timer, two diodes and some passives. All it has to do is supply ~10mA to the upper gate driver.

That's pretty much everything. Here's what you should do:

1 Build the High side gate driver and test that it works.

2 Build the rest of a single half bridge.

3 Test that it switches correctly

4 connect it in the half bridge configuration to your transformer with a split set of electrolytic caps on the other side and try driving something.

Hopefully it works.

Comment: thanks for your comment that showed me a lot of info. first to answer your question i have a pwm variable freq 0-10khz (mosfet gate 20 volts)  to step up voltage to 3500 volts to power a series LC circuit. witch is forward voltage lc circuit. my problem is that i have a pwm at 20 volts. i need to get the pwm to 3500 volts. i got a transformer designed and built its a regular transformer that is designed to handle 150-10khz 1 amp. my problem is that i can research different topology but if i have never seen them i cant research them and learn how they work.

Comment: if you dont mind what would you call the topology that you gave in your first example so i can research. also thanks for your time. any info would be greatfull

Comment: The series LC circuit is operating at resonance? That's why you need the variable frequency right? The frequency range matters. There's no way any transformer based circuit can operate at 0Hz. If you can describe your application a bit more that would help. The load on the output for example.

Comment: again thanks for your input. but what i really dont understand is how would i regulate the curre nt flow. if the primary coil is 4 ohms volts is 60 volt. the current flow will be 15 amps.  i need to regulate current and have the still work transformer working

Comment: correct richard it will be at resonance at 3500 volts is the end goal

Comment: i will be changing the cap many times so the freq will change due to the cap being changed

Comment: ya the transformer operates from 150hz to 10khz. i paid alot of money for it so it does work and i have tested it. and it will work on those freq. i will be hiting resonance of the lc ciricit. it needs to change freq because i will be changing the cap. it will be a variable cap. so freq will have to change with it. the output of transformer will have 0 load its just a lc circuit. it is to test caps. no other load will be added the the circuit

Comment: I finished off the answer. I think it's all pretty clear.

Comment: HB configuration would be the best, but with providing a small dead time between high- and low-gate drive signals.

Comment: ok thanks richard i will put those circuits together in the next day or so. i should have everything here to compete it. thats for your advice i will see if that will get the job done. i will let you know how it works in a day or so